# How to display grouped data from recursive SQL query in a Twig HTML table?

Tags: php, sql, twig

I want to be able to display data from a SQL database (using PDO) and present it in an HTML table, however, I am having trouble understanding how to include a subquery in the results of my original query. I have gotten close to my desired result by using the GROUP_CONCAT function to group the data as comma separated values.

Using Twig to populate the HTML table with the desired values, but I can't figure out how to group certain values (course names) underneath the student.

```
`PHP
SELECT classes.ID, classes.PIDM, classes.fName, classes.lName, classes.advisorOneFirst, classes.advisorOneLast, classes.advisorOneEmail, 
GROUP_CONCAT(classes.courseTitle) AS courses
FROM classes
WHERE term = :cterm AND (classes.MGrade = "F" OR classes.MGrade = "F~" OR classes.MGrade = "D" OR classes.MGrade = "D~")
GROUP BY classes.ID
ORDER BY lName ASC

`HTML
{% for student in classes %}
<tr>
<td>{{student.fName}}</td>
<td>{{student.courses}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

To illustrate my webpage looks like this:

```
student1 course1,course2
student2 course3,course4
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
student1 course1
         course2
student2 course3
         course4
```

Also, using

```
GROUP_CONCAT(classes.courseTitle SEPARATOR "<br>")
```

or any other substitution results in:

```
student1 course1<br>course2
student2 course3<br>course4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig automatically escapes your variables to protect against XSS attacks, which is why using the `<br>` tags wasn't working. Using the `GROUP_CONCAT(classes.courseTitle SEPARATOR "<br>")`, update your twig to use the [raw](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html) filter:

```
{% for student in classes %}
<tr>
<td>{{student.fName}}</td>
<td>{{student.courses|raw}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

---

**Update**

Using the raw filter could produce other issues depending on the characters in courses. A better approach would be to use a character you can split on as the separator in `group_concat`, then split on that character and loop each course in twig. For example, if you used a semicolon as the character separator,

Your group concat would look like this:

```sql
GROUP_CONCAT(classes.courseTitle SEPARATOR ';')
```

And your twig would like this:

```
{% for student in classes %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ student.fName }}</td>
    <td>
    {% for course in student.courses|split(';') %}
        {{ course }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I won't be able to test this until tomorrow, but thanks for the help! Will definitely use the safer, second approach. Is there any reason to not use |split(',') without SEPARATOR ';' or are you just trying to avoid edge cases like "Hist. of Mid,Late- Inst'l Art"?

Comment: @user19550 yes, I used a semicolon because it seems like a safer character to split on. What character you use depends on your data. You should use something that will never be in the course title. You can also use multiple characters if needed, something like `~|~`

Comment: tested and works with a minor change: {% for course in courses|split(';') %} should be {% for course in student.courses|split(';') %} marked as answered!

Comment: @user19550I Thanks for the update, I've updated the answer with the minor correction you pointed out. FYI, you should accept the answer so future readers know it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

given a generalized table:

```
 myTable
=========
foo | bar
----+----
foo1|bar1
foo2|bar2
foo1|bar3
foo2|bar4
```

SQL

```
SELECT foo,
GROUP_CONCAT(bar SEPARATOR "@@@") AS bars
FROM myTable
GROUP BY foo
```

HTML

```
{% for foobar in myTable %}
<tr>
    <td>{{foobar.foo}}</td>
    <td>
    {% for bar in foobar.bars|split("@@@") %}
    {{bar}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

webpage presentation

```
foo1 bar1
     bar3
foo2 bar2
     bar4
```